# Sending commands to and receiving their output from a running Python application (via remote connection)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, read-eval-print-loop

I have a long-running server application written in Python 3, which I would like to interactively debug from time to time. For that I would like to run Python commands "within" the server application process, inspect the values of global variables etc., like in a REPL or the standardd Python console.

It seems the [Python standard library's `code` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html) and its `InteractiveConsole` class seems to be what I am looking for. I was thinking of running that in a separate thread so that the main application is not blocked while I communicate with it.

However, it seems that class provides interaction via standard input and output. That might not be exactly what I need. Is there a way to make that interactive console listen / connect to a socket and send input and output through this socket, so that I can connect to the console via a TCP connection?

Or is there another, better way to implement my requirement without this `code` module?

Comment: People use `logging` for that purpose. Do you really have to connect to the "main" process or are able to start extra process (separate interpreter) on the same machine?

Comment: A common way is to dump the debug info, internal state, statistics or whatever has to be checked to a file when a special signal is caught (e.g. SIGUSR1). Isn't that good enough for debugging purposes?

Comment: Well, of course I do log various data to a log file. It's just that I can't log **all** data **all the time**, so I need to select what I think is "the mose valuable" data to log. If I could, however, connect to the app and interact via such a console/REPL, then I would be able to retieve really **all** data at any time ...

Comment: To achieve the basic functionality a TCP echo server with a line like `result = eval inputline` added should do. No comfort like variable name autocompletion and no security too.